# Javascript: Check if duplicate key exist, Add corresponding children for the duplicate key

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out a sample array of object in which I have following key value pair. I need to find key which I am splitting based on underscore, first splitted value will become key and second will become the array of object of that key. I am getting duplicate key which needs to be unique and then add values into it.

```
const arr = [
    {label: 'id', key: 'wfc_id'},
    {label: 'Name', key: 'wfc_name'},
    {label: 'Age', key: 'wfc_age'},
    {label: 'id', key: 'ga_id'},
    {label: 'Name', key: 'ga_name'},
    {label: 'Age', key: 'ga_age'},
    {label: 'Name', key: 'rtc_name'},
    {label: 'id', key: 'rtc_id'},
]

Desired Ouput:
output = {
    wfc: {id:true, name:true, age: true},
    ga: {id:true, name:true, age: true},
    rtc: {id:true, name:true},
}
```

I tried following code:

```
let output = Object.assign({},arr.map((item) => {
    let str = item.key.split('_');
    let obj = {};
    obj[str[0]] = {
        [str[1]]: true
    }
    return obj
})
);
console.log(output);
```

But it giving me output as

```
{
  "0": {
    "wfc": {
      "id": true
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "wfc": {
      "name": true
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "wfc": {
      "age": true
    }
  },
  "3": {
    "ga": {
      "id": true
    }
  },
  "4": {
    "ga": {
      "name": true
    }
  },
  "5": {
    "ga": {
      "age": true
    }
  },
 .......
}
```

I require if key already exits then add array/object for it's corresponding key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [map() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array. To transform the output, you need to [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), also called a "fold."

```
arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const split = curr.key.split('_');
  const identifier = split[0];
  const property = split[1];
  acc[identifier] = { ...acc[identifier], [property]: true };
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off [using `reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in this case. You present it with an initial object (accumulator), and then add to it over the iterations.

```js
const arr = [
  {label: 'id', key: 'wfc_id'},
  {label: 'Name', key: 'wfc_name'},
  {label: 'Age', key: 'wfc_age'},
  {label: 'id', key: 'ga_id'},
  {label: 'Name', key: 'ga_name'},
  {label: 'Age', key: 'ga_age'},
  {label: 'Name', key: 'rtc_name'},
  {label: 'id', key: 'rtc_id'},
]

const output = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {

  // Destructure the array into a key and value
  let [ key, value ] = item.key.split('_');

  // If the key doesn't exist on the accumulator
  // add an empty object
  acc[key] = acc[key] || {};

  // And then set the object property to true
  acc[key][value] = true;

  // Return the accumulator for the next iteration
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: You should select one of these answers as correct by ticking the tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use reduce for your case.

```js
const arr = [
  { label: "id", key: "wfc_id" },
  { label: "Name", key: "wfc_name" },
  { label: "Age", key: "wfc_age" },
  { label: "id", key: "ga_id" },
  { label: "Name", key: "ga_name" },
  { label: "Age", key: "ga_age" },
  { label: "Name", key: "rtc_name" },
  { label: "id", key: "rtc_id" },
];

const o = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
  const [key, prop] = b.key.split("_");
  a[key] ? (a[key][prop] = true) : (a[key] = { [prop]: true });
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(o);
```